# How to numerically solve this system of arbitrary number of differential equations?

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

How can I solve a system of k differential equations with derivatives appearing in every equation? I am trying to use Scipy's solve_ivp.

All the equations are of the following form:

[equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gqqn.png)

How can this system of equations be numerically solved using any solver? using solve_ivp, it seems you should be able to write every equation independent of the other ones, which seems not possible in this case when we have more than 2 equations.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `C[i]=B[i,i]` then you can transform the equations to the linear system `B*z'=A`. This can be solved as

```
zdot = numpy.linalg.solve(B,A)
```

so that the derivative is this constant solution of a constant linear system, and the resulting solution for `z` is linear, `z(t)=z(0)+zdot*t`.

Comment: A,B,C are functions of z_i and B_ii can not be set eqaul to C_i. This is a case of numerical methods.

Comment: Why not? The original diagonal of `B` is not used, thus it can be set to `C`. That `A` and `B` are not constant does not change the nature of the linear system, so now you have to solve `zdot = numpy.linalg.solve(B(z),A(z))` at every call of the derivatives function. More effort is required if the system is structurally sparse and you want to re-use some of the sparsity information for all calls.